# Resize SVG on Mobile

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, responsiveness

How can I resize my SVG Logo for responsiveness on Mobile?

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e4fk3u5/) and my code is below:

```css
body {
    background:black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    svg {
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <title>Logo</title>
  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g id="Your-Score" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Desktop-Your-Score" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(-23.000000, -24.000000)" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gill Sans" letter-spacing="1.16666663" font-size="28" sketch:alignment="middle" fill="#FFFFFF">
      <g id="Header" sketch:type="MSTextLayer">
        <g id="Primary-Nav-[home]-Copy">
          <g id="Logo" transform="translate(23.000000, 18.000000)">
            <text id="TOMORROW’S">
              <tspan x="0.0328778028" y="27">TOMORROW’S</tspan>
              <tspan x="36.2975262" y="58">SCORE</tspan>
            </text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For scaling via the img element to work, the SVG image needs to have its width, height and viewBox attributes set inside it. Here is how that looks:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="70px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 70 70">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24" style="stroke:#006600; fill:#00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

When setting the width, height and viewBox property, you tell the browser what part of the virtual canvas to draw. The view box tells the upper left and lower right corner of the virtual canvas. Thus, if the image is scaled to a size bigger than that, the whole image is scaled up, instead of just making the virtual canvas bigger (resulting in white space next to the SVG shapes in the image).

For more clarification search for viewBox property related to SVG.

Always Set Image Width Via CSS Properties

Do not use the width and height attributes of the img element. It will not give the desired effect. The browsers treat these attributes differently than the corresponding CSS properties.

Answer (score 4):

Use your SVG inside of an `<img>` tag, for example:

```
<img src="my_SVG_file.svg" alt="" />
```

Then you can use standard CSS to affect the `<img>` tag & make it mobile responsive.

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/bVZKjg)

Comment: loading an svg from an `<img>` tag will disable all scripting or external CSS styling on this svg. Op's code doesn't seem to have any like it is right now but it is often necessary to keep inline svg as inline svg...

Comment: This doesn't seem to resize for me. Is it possible to resize it at a certain break point in my CSS?

Comment: I updated the pen with your ``@media query`` to show it's working.